# Google Sheets API v4 Values.update syntax

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Cannot get the right/correct syntax for `Values.update`, there is no examples of code for Google Apps Script on Google documentation. Tried to use the code pattern from `batchUpdate` limiting the range to one but it is not working. Could anyone please advise the correct syntax for `Values.update`? Here is the code:

```
function updateOneCell() {
  var spreadsheetId = "someSpreadsheetId";
  var request = {
    "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED",
    "data": [
      {
        "range": "Sheet1!BW7",
        "majorDimension": "ROWS",
        "values": [[new Date()]]
      }
    ]
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(request, spreadsheetId);
}
```

It is giving the following error:

> Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 3-4 only

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

1. About error

> Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 3-4 only

This means that for `Sheets` of Advanced Google Services, `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update()` has 3 or 4 arguments as follows.

- `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(resource, spreadsheetId, range)`
- `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(resource, spreadsheetId, range, optionalArgs)`

2. About limitations

Range of `BW7` cannot be used. Because the following error occurs.

> Range ('Sheet1'!BW7) exceeds grid limits. Max rows: 1000, max columns: 26

The modified script reflected those is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function updateOneCell() {
    var spreadsheetId = "someSpreadsheetId";
    var request = {
        majorDimension: "ROWS",
        values: [[new Date()]]
    };
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(
      request,
      spreadsheetId,
      "Sheet1!A1",
      {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"}
    );
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: thank you very much. It works fine now. Only `new Date()` is getting inserted in text/string format, is it possible to insert `new Date()` in datetime format? Now it is inserting it as `"Tue Sep 05 08:59:24 GMT+01:00 2017"`, is it possible to insert it in the following datetime format without " ": 05.09.2017 08:59:24

Comment: @Din Welcome. Thank you, too. Can you post your additional question as a new question?

Comment: here you go, i just posted the additional question as a new question. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46055607/google-sheets-api-v4-inserting-new-date-in-datetime-format).

Comment: @Din And... the question is deleted :(

Answer (score 1):

worked for me:

```
sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(
      {
        spreadsheetId,
        range: 'Sheet1!B3:C4',
        valueInputOption:'RAW',
        resource: {
          values: [
            ['B3', new Date()],
            ['C3', 'C4']
          ],
        }
      }
    )
```

Comment: How can Google not document this? And how does anybody know what to pass?

Comment: I struggled a bit too to find the documentation, you can find the documentation for the GoogleAPI Client library here :
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/sheets/classes/Resource$Spreadsheets$Values.html

And the REST API here:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange